# Add tab in product magento 2

Tags: tabs

I am building a new site and i am facing a problem.
I want to add in each product some info in a tab. so this tab should be a free text in each product.
I saw modules that you make tabs and then assign it in product. This way i have to make 15000 tabs!
Is there an option to add in my product backend a field that i  can add the text i need and display it as tab on frontend?

My theme has a custom tab ready. please see
[image]

I have made one attribute named "text"
Please can you inform me what i must write in the custom tab data in order for the "text" attribute to span in custom tab?

This way i will write anything i need in this text attribute in each product and display it in the custom tab i already have.

Please advise
Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [blog](https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-create-a-new-custom-tab-in-the-product-detail-page-in-magento-2/) , it is as per your requirements. There are instructions for how you can create a custom tab and show custom content in it. Also show product details or static block.

I hope it will help you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My theme has a custom tab already. The problem is that this is general for all products. What i need is in each product to add content and be visible on frontend. Can i add there an option to display a text atrribute? please see photo https://prnt.sc/11t8b9c. This way i will be able to add content in an attribute and display it in this custom tab.

Comment: Yes you can. On the blog there is a section **Show product details in custom tab** by using it you can display product attribute data in your custom tab. Also please update your question with detailed requirements. Thanks!